# Using shapefile polygons in Spotfire to select points

Tags: shapefile, tibco, spotfire

I have a map in Spotfire with several different polygons overlaying it. These polygons are all stored in a shapefile and loaded on the map as a feature layer. Also on the map are several xy points with data associated to them. I would like to be able to select a polygon and in turn, that polygon select all the xy points inside of it.

Thanks,

-Andrew Pruet

Comment: very good question, I'd be happy with it's solution too, however I'm afraid there is no way for it without coding.